# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'glib' in Python3

Tags: package-management, python, python3, glib

I am getting a `ModuleNotFoundError` every time I try to import `glib` with Python3. 
I tried importing it with Python2 and there was no problem. 

My Python3 version is **Python 3.7.5** and default Python version is **Python 2.7.17** . 
The error I get looks like:

```py
>>> import glib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'glib'
```

I saw that there are some recommendations to use `from gi.repository import GLib` instead but I cannot do that because I get that error initially when I try to execute a .sh file , so I don't manulally import it.

I also tried the commands :

 `sudo apt-get install python-gtk2`

 `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-dbus`

 but these didn't help. 

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install

> Introspection data for GLib, GObject, Gio and GModule

package with

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-glib-2.0
```

as this is currently a way to `import GLib`.
See real [source code examples](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=from+gi.repository+import+GLib&literal=1) from real applications in Debian (and in Ubuntu).